# Looking For Land Emissions/ Soil Contamination Chemical Levels Data

Tags: data-request, soils

I'm looking for any data showing soil/land emissions and/or soil contamination levels for the state of Pennsylvania. The only sources I found were on the EPA (using the TRI database) and this data source (https://mrdata.usgs.gov/ds-801/).

Note: I'll also accept soil data for the USA as a whole as well.

Comment: FAO may have it for the entire US, among other countries: http://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data